# Querying SQL Sever 2008 clustering datamining model

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-mining

I know how to [get list of clusters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280440%28v=sql.100%29.aspx#bkmk_Query3) and their properties like population and characteristics.

```
SELECT NODE_NAME, NODE_CAPTION ,NODE_SUPPORT, NODE_DESCRIPTION
FROM TM_Clustering.CONTENT
WHERE NODE_TYPE = 5 AND NODE_SUPPORT > 1000
```

but I need to get a list of links between these clusters. links are shown in image bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
CALL System.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.System.DataMining.Clustering.GetNodeGraph('ModelName',0)
```